# customable input format hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm writing a program with Java Hadoop for **`MapReduce`**. I have some problems with **`TextInputFormat`** because it takes as input a **`LongWritable`** but in my code I don't have any of it ( I have a new class written). So I need a *new class* **`InputFormat`** that takes as input an instance of my new class. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to worry - `TextInputFormat` is right for you.

In `TextInputFormat` you'll get each row of data as a `Text` object in the mapper's value. The `LongWritable` is just the byte offset of the start of the line in the file. It's pretty rare to use this `LongWritable`, and most MR jobs ignore it in the mapper. You can use this input format without changing your data.

Answer (score 0):

For TextInputFormat, framework reads each line with lineoffset as key and line as value. If it is text data and each line is record, then you should use TextInputFormat, as part of mapper you need to process each record.